# How to use common functionallity when creating a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to create a `DLL` with `implicit-linking` that `uses Core functionallities` in my application that is shared between projects (e.g. Containers, Algorithms). The `DLL` compiles itself, however when trying to compile the whole application, I receive:

`CommonFunctionallity.lib(TheFunctionallity.obj) : error LNK2005: ... already defined in AnotherProject.lib(TheDLLThatUsesTheCommonFunctionallity.dll)`

`fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

, because the other project uses that same functionality.

How could I tackle this problem? I could use `/FORCE:MULTIPLE to the Linker’s Command Line` but I have read that it is a dirty solution.

Comment: Sounds like you have just discovered even more basic functionality, that could be put in a Core.dll and then used by the others.

Comment: @BoP Just to be 100% sure, your suggestion is to create Core.dll (the `DLL` that uses that common functionallity) that is implicitly-linked with the `DLL` that uses that functionality, and is also implicitly-linked to the other projects. Like doing static links (.lib) between projects? `Application.exe <-> Core.dll <-> Other.dll`

Comment: @BoP Kinda late, but have finished it. You can move your comment to answer so it can get accepted